# React native android build version code not updating

Tags: android, react-native

I have edited the versionCode in both the android\app\build.gradle file :

```
versionCode 2
versionName "2.0"
```

and I have updated the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
package="com.reactnativeapp"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0"
```

BUT I still get this error when I try to release an update to my app on google play store!

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle 
because you already have one with version code 1.
```

I have tried running

```
gradlew clean
```

in the android folder and rebuilding the project and nothing has worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have your `versionCode` and `versionName` set inside `defaultConfig` like this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = 2
        versionName = "2.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

You might have it set up for a debug-only config, which wouldn't change for release builds.

Comment: great answer!! Thanks a lot.